# pysnmp: Get Command responder without engine id

Tags: pysnmp

Using pysnmp , can I create a simple v2c get command responder for sysDesc , without engine-id ?

I am working on an application where I need to create a responder thread during system initialization.

Comment: What exactly do you mean - no engine-id? No `SnmpEngine` object?

Comment: Yes Ilya … right

Comment: So why are you trying to avoid creating SnmpEngine?

Answer (score 0):

For as long as you are using SNMPv3 framework, everything there revolves around the concept of SNMP engine. So you have to use it.

But if you resort to older SNMP design (which is SNMP v1/v2c) - there is no SNMP engine there at all.

Here you will find the [example script](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects-over-ipv4-and-ipv6.py) which implements SNMP *Command Responder* over SNMP v1/v2c architecture. The script has a some extra functionality (like MIB object and IPv6 support) which you can just drop.

Comment: Thanks Ilya I will try this out .